# Text in edit text not vertically aligned in android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

[image]

here's screen I talk about, look at the two orange edit text they are looking so weird cause the text itself which is 2 and 30 isn't vertically aligned and as you see there's no padding or anything abnormal in my xml, I tried to make gravity vertically aligned but it didn't work, so what should I do to make it vertically aligned

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
        android:ems="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Body2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_text_view" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210296/discussion-on-question-by-karim-ata-text-in-edit-text-not-vertically-aligned-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to remove your Edittext textAppearance android:textAppearance="@style/Body2"